# Select most recent entry where timestamp is from the past hour

Tags: mysql

I've tried multiple ways, all of them resulting in incorrect rows returned, so far I've tried

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1 AND timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1

.... AND timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

Both of which returned one result each - as expected, but is not the most recent for that ID.

How could I get this to work?

Example:

`index|id|timestamp`
`----------------------------`
`1    |1 |2015-06-22 15:08:44`
`2    |1 |2015-06-21 12:09:16`
`3    |2 |2015-06-22 15:12:32`
`4    |1 |2015-06-22 12:33:49`
`5    |3 |2015-06-20 00:00:00`

Would return the row with time 2015-06-22 15:08:44 if asking for ID 1, 2015-06-22 15:12:32 if asking for ID 2, and no rows returned if asking for ID 3
Assuming current datetime is 2015-06-22 15:mm:ss

Comment: Please add a sample of the input and expected output

Comment: `'timestamp'` you should not be using quotes for the column name in the query.

Comment: `'timestamp'` is a string literal. `timestamp` (no quotes) would be your field.

Comment: `'timestamp'` and `timestamp` both returned the same results, that was me just playing around and I didn't know it made a difference. Adding a sample now

Comment: In title you have written past hour, but in query you are writing, interval 1 day. Which 1 is correct??

Comment: You are still using `'timestamp'` in your `ORDER BY`.

Comment: After seeing @AbhikChakraborty's comment I fixed the apostrophes and tested but still returned the same results

Comment: You may need to quote timestamp with ` (backquote) as timestamp is a reserved word (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html)

Comment: @PaulF Still returning the same results

Comment: Have you tried using the TIMESTAMPDIFF function : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table 
where TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `timestamp`, NOW())=0
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I suggest you add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are sometimes good enough, but code+explanation answers are always better.

Comment: @Barranka : the code-only answer was a follow up to my earlier comment (with reference to MySQL website) - so I thought further explanation was just duplicating effort